# Position a relative <span> after an absolute <a>

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am trying to position a span element with relative positioning (and displayed as inline-block) after a a element with absolute positioning (and displayed as inline-block too). These two elements are in a li element. I succeeded with a bit of javascript, but if there is a css solution, I would really love to know it!

Here is the code I'm trying to "debug" http://jsfiddle.net/eKEEa/1/

Thanks in advance for helping!

Comment: What do you want the final layout to look like? The two next to each other? Do you need relative positioning or is that how you were trying to solve your problem?

Comment: Exactly! I want the "span" element to be after the "a".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed your CSS from relative to positioning to `float:left` and removed the `display:inline-block`. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/eKEEa/4/

```
ul li{
    list-style: none;
    width: auto;
    height: 45px;
}
ul a{
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 10px 10px 5px 10px;
    background: #ffffff;
    color:#000;
}
ul span{
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 10px 10px 5px 10px;
    background: #2e8ab8;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: I leave the inline-block, and it works fine! Anyway, thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Happy to help. I really wouldn't recommend inline-block as it has very strange browser support. By floating left it automatically sets the display to block, so I wouldn't recommend changing it to inline-block.